# 'Failed to open/create the internal network' when specifying config.vm.network in vagrant file

Tags: networking, vagrant, virtualbox, devops, system-administration

When I try to create a virtual box with private IP in vagrant file with the line `config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.0.15.11"`

Then it's showing an error like:

> Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #3' (VERR_SUPDRV_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND).

If I comment that line in the vagrant file and run the vagrant up, then the vagrant box gets created without any error in virtualbox, but I want four vagrant boxes with private_network IP to be configured so that they can communicate to each other.

How can I do that?

Comment: do you have virtualbox guest addition installed ? also try with another IP in 172.16.0.0/12 or 192.168.0.0/16 range

Comment: @FrédéricHenri You can do this without guest additions.

Comment: @MattSchuchard clear but usually guest additions help for networking and synced folder

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment, so posting some solution that might help you.

I normally use `private_network` for my host-only adapter. If I need to connect to the router to communicate with another device on my network (or connect guest machines also in my host), I use bridged-adapter..

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.236.77"
config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "172.20.2.77", bridge: "en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)"
```

This one is for Mac also using VirtualBox. Result: NAT, Host-only, Bridged.

```
ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:60:FC:47
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:9B:1F:AA
          inet addr:192.168.236.77  Bcast:192.168.236.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:AB:A1:3F
          inet addr:172.20.2.77  Bcast:172.20.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```